# Android Error :You must supply layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

Sorry because my title similar with many others on `StackOverFlow` but none of those solution meet with my problem.

I'm designing a layout use `Relative Layout`. After design in code view, when I change to graphic view, Eclipse notices :

> You must supply a layout_width attribute.
>
> You must supply a layout_height attribute.

. When I run this program, will notice error in LogCat

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You
>   must supply a layout_width attribute.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:text="Sam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="39256493"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>        

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That XML looks correct - is this the only layout XML that you have? Check the others to ensure the error is in none of those.

Comment: I got this same error. It seems like if your xml layout is not well formed you might get this error. It worked after i correct invalid xml tags in the layout. hth!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your xmlns line should read `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.
That'll probably fix your issue.

**EDIT:**

Quoting Google in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html:

> xmlns:android Defines the Android namespace.
>
> This attribute should
>   always be set to "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".

When you are using a XML file like the layout files you are using, the attributes you can use within that same file are defined by a schema.

xmlns is short for "XML namespace". You're defining inside your XML a namespace of keywords "android:", and that's why you need to declare all your attributes with "android:" in the beginning, such as `android:layout_height` or `android:layout_width`.

The namespace should be pointing to a valid schema, which should be pointing to a URLcontaining that exact schema. If the URL doesn't point to a valid schema, your XML attributes won't be recognized, which was the problem you were having.

I hope you could understand my explanation.

If you want to read more about XML namespaces and schemas, I can point you straight to W3Schools and Wikipedia: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema.

Comment: Oh. thanks :) It works for me. But can you explain for me why, please :) I think it's just an `URL`, so not important :(

Comment: Sure! I edited my post and explained it. Tell me if you need further clarifications, I'll be happy to help with what I can.

Comment: Oh. thanks so much :D I'm new comer of XML. I have read those concept before but don't carefully. With your explanation and your link, I have understand more :)

Comment: "android" is an alias for the schema you are referencing. If you changed "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to "xmlns:droid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" then you could prefix all of your attributes with (for example) "droid:layout_width". As long as the alias is unique for your .axml then all is good. To save time you can alias with just "a" which then allows you to define attributes as "a:layout_width" ... saves a lot of typing and who doesn't get tired of typeing "android:"

Answer (score 2):

It might be irrelevant but namespace tag attracted my attention, as [the usual one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) is:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Oh. thanks :) It works for me. But can you explain for me why, please :) I think it's just an URL, so not important :(

Comment: The URL is the location of an xml schema file. A schema file provides a data definition for a given data set that falls within a "namespacce". It defines what the allowable structure of an XML file can be (eg. .axml must begin with a layout element of some kind ...) and the data types that are allowable for each element (eg. id must be stringified ref to resource identifier) . By adding the    "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" reference to your .axml you are stating that the xml that follows must conform to the shema located at that url.

Answer (score 1):

You should change line : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com`
to line : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`

I have met this error and It;s painful. But I cannot explain why.

Hope it works for your :)

Comment: Oh. thanks :) It works for me. But can you explain for me why, please :) I think it's just an URL, so not important :(

Comment: The URL "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is the location of a schema file. A schema file defines the allowable data types and values for a given namespace. a

Answer (score -1):

Could you try doing projects > clean. If that doesn't work try changing your relative layout's arguments with match_parent.